# Displaying an image using jinja2 on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a database of images. I want to display all the images in the database using a jinja2 template.

I send the database objects as follow:

```
class Default_tiles(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  image = db.BlobProperty(default=None)


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    # get all the default tiles in the database 
    default_tiles_query = Default_tiles.all()
    defaultTiles = default_tiles_query.fetch(10)

    template_values = {
        'defaultTiles': defaultTiles  # contain all the defaut tiles to be displayed 
    }

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

The jinja2 template to display each image in each object in Default_tiles is:

```
<body>  
  {% for defaultTile in defaultTiles %}
    {{ defaultTile.image }}
  {% endfor %}
</body>
```

When this is run I get the following error log:

**File "/Users/jamiefearon/Desktop/Development/My Programs/GAE Fully functional website with css, javascript and images/index.html", line 24, in top-level template code
    {{ defaultTile.image }}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)**

I suspect that I am doing something wrong with the line `{{ defaultTile.image }}`

Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just throw binary data into html and display the image, you need to display the images using the [IMG](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) element.

You need to serve your images using a handler or display the images using [inline base64 data](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any examples I can look at to get a better understanding of how to do this? i.e how to display all the images from a database in the datastore